# What is the most accurate depiction of the StealthX X-Wing?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I'm creating a Lego model based off of it, and wish to know what is the most accurate depiction in art, games, or videos. I've been going off this picture so far since it's the most detailed, but I don't get the whole picture.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found a picture of a lego SteathX [image]

Link: https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/design.page?idModel=139998

Comment: maybe i should add my current depiction:

Comment: https://www.mecabricks.com/en/models/mLvznyJJvAw

Comment: Your picture seems to have everything that I’ve seen.